# LaTeX hyperref link goes to wrong page when i clicked at the content there

Tags: latex, tex, tableofcontents, hyperref

i would like to ask how to use the \hyperref because i've googled loads of loads of answers but i can't find. i've created my own TOC. then i included \hyperref package. Then the contents are automatically hyperlinks which is good. but then it went to the wrong pages. i've googled a lot but i couldn't find answer. The contents that i clicked goes to the wrong page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{hyperref}
% %\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


% %\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\hyperlink{contents}{Contents}}
% %\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\hyperref[contents]{\arabic{page}}}

\begin{document}

\input{coverPage}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\pagebreak

% % (1) ==============================================
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. Introduction}
\input{introduction}
\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{2. References}
\input{references}
\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{3. Glossary}
\input{glossary}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}\tableofcontents`. The bigger question is: Why are you inserting this manually?

Comment: @Werner my lecturer thought us how to do this.. i dont know any other better way to add contents.. lol is there any automatic way other than this manual way?

Comment: You should use `\chapter{<chap title>}` to insert a chapter. I've guessing you're doing something different inside `introduction.tex` and others.

Comment: @Werner Do you want to write an answer? Or close as unclear?

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that `\chapter` sets itself on a new page, so issuing `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chapter title>}` *before* `\chapter` may point to an incorrect page.

Also, your `\tableofcontents` might be more than a single page. So, issuing `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}` *after* `\tableofcontents` - a `\chapter*` - might again point to an incorrect page.

The best solution is to use the following setup:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chapter title>}
% <your \chapter or \chapter*>
```

This will ensure that `\addcontentsline` is issued on the same page as `\chapter` or `\chapter*`.